# Save data to firebase Realtime database from Android service

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I want to save user's location after every 30 seconds to firebase realtime database from android service,my service stops when i add firebase, there is no crash log, any suggestions? or best solution to achieve this? Thanks

```
public class LocationService extends Service {
    double pLatitude, pLongitude;
    private DatabaseReference mDatabase;
    FirebaseUser user;

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Service Started", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return START_STICKY;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        //service stops(crashes) on below two lines
            mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
            user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();

        final Handler handler = new Handler();
        Timer timer = new Timer();
        TimerTask doAsynchronousTask = new TimerTask() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                handler.post(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        try {
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Service Started", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            pushtofirebase(getLocation());

                        } catch (Exception e) {
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        };
        timer.schedule(doAsynchronousTask, 0, 30000);

    }

    private void pushtofirebase(GPSTracker gps) {
            pLatitude = gps.getLatitude();
            pLongitude = gps.getLongitude();


            mDatabase.child("location").child(user.getUid()).push().setValue(String.valueOf(pLatitude));
            mDatabase.child("location").child(user.getUid()).setValue(pLongitude);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        Toast.makeText(this, "Service Destroyed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    private GPSTracker getLocation() {

        GPSTracker gps = new GPSTracker(getApplicationContext());
        if (gps.canGetLocation()) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), gps.getLongitude() + " " + gps.getLatitude(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        } else {
            gps.showSettingsAlert();
        }
        return gps;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please add the log report if your application is crashing

Comment: pLatitude = gps.getLatitude();
        pLongitude = gps.getLongitude();

        Map<String,Double> map=new HashMap();
        map.put("lat",pLatitude);
        map.put("lng",pLongitude);        
        mDatabase.child("location").child(user.getUid()).push().setValue(map);

Comment: @akhilesh0707 but services stops in the start of oncreate method, check comment

Comment: @RakshitNawani app is not crashing, it shows a crash dialog but actually it was for service, activity is working perfect

Comment: @RakshitNawani app is not crashing, it shows a crash dialog but actually it was for service, activity is working perfect

Comment: There must be a crash, attach the debugger and try to find the error

Comment: have you added necessary permissions in manifest and manages android M runtime permissions?

Comment: @Thesoham24 yes, I am getting location, service  stops when i add firebase code in service.

Answer (score 0):

it may be a native crash change the logcat crash level to verbose and application to no filter 
[image]